# What is the rationale for adding semaphore to C++20, while it was deemed too dangerous for C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, semaphore, c++20

I seem to remember the rationale for not adding semaphores to C++11 being that they are too easy to use incorrectly and the programmers are better to use mutexes and condition variables.

If that's so, what is the rationale for finally adding the semaphore to C++20?

Comment: Can you cite your claim about C++11?  Because if false, your wuestion becomes insensible.

Comment: @Scheff If you mean [this paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0514r4.pdf) then the abstract is interesting (but not, perhaps, motivation in itself).

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, I do not think I can find the source. I remember I had some trouble finding it years ago and I do not think it would be easier now.

Comment: @G.M. I meant exactly this paper [Efficient concurrent waiting for C++20](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0514r4.pdf). ;-)